# I am making a code where I create persons, marry them, make them give birth etc but I fail at printing them

Tags: c

so at first, I didnt know I had to use struct so I failed miserably and had to change my whole code but now it can't print anything :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct p {
    char* name;
    int year_of_birth;
    char* sex;
    struct p* mother;
    struct p* father;
    struct p* significant_other;
    struct p** children;


}typedef Person;
```

this is where I define my structure

```
Person* person_constructor(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex);
Person* birth(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex, Person *mother);

void display_person(Person* p);
void marry_them(Person *p1, Person *p2);
void display_family(Person* family[], int n);
Person* sibling(Person p, int print);
```

here are my function definitions

```
int main() {
    Person* p1 = person_constructor("Abbas", 1970, "male");
    Person* p2 = person_constructor("Sidika", 1970, "female");
    marry_them(p1, p2);
    Person* p3 = person_constructor("Pinar", 1990, "female");
    Person* p4 = birth("Siamak", 1990, "male", p2);
    marry_them(p3, p4);
    Person* p5 = birth("Guzide", 1990, "female", p2);
    Person* p6 = person_constructor("Fatih", 1990, "male");
    marry_them(p5, p6);
    Person* p7 = birth("Berkecan", 2010, "male", p3);
    Person* p8 = birth("Ekinsu", 2010, "female", p3);
    Person* p9 = birth("Canim", 2010, "female", p5);



    display_person(p1);
```

my main where I summon people, marry them etc and most important part,

```
return 0;
}
Person* person_constructor(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex)
{
    Person *p = calloc(1,sizeof(*p));
    strcpy(p->name, name);
    p->year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
    strcpy(p->sex, sex);


    return p;
}



void display_person(Person* p)
{

    printf("================\n");
    printf("Name   : %s \n",p->name);
    printf("Sex    : %s \n",p->sex);
    printf("Year   : %d \n",p->year_of_birth);
    if (strcmp(p->father,"") == 0){
        printf("Father : NA \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Father : %s \n", p->father);
    }
    if (strcmp(p->mother,"") == 0){
        printf("Mother : NA \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Mother : %s \n", p->mother);
    }
    if (strcmp((const char *) p->significant_other, "") == 0){
        printf("Sig.O  : NA \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Sig.O  : %s \n", p->significant_other);
    }
    if (strcmp(p->children,"") == 0){
        printf("Child 1 : NA \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Child 1 : %s \n", p->children[0]);
    }
    if (strcmp(p->children,"") == 0){
        printf("Child 2 : NA \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Child 2 : %s \n", p->children[1]);
    }
}

void marry_them(Person *p1, Person *p2)
{
    strcpy(p1->significant_other, p2->name);
    strcpy(p2->significant_other, p1->name);

}
Person* birth(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex, Person *mother) {
    Person *p = person_constructor(name, year_of_birth, sex);
    strcpy(p->mother, mother->name);
    strcpy(p->father, mother->significant_other);

    return p;
}
void display_family(Person* family[], int n)
{
for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
{
   display_person(family[i]);
}
}
Person* sibling(Person p, int print)
{


}
```

these are my functions, I wrote them for char mother[20] kind of code instead of struct mother and I am tangled. I can't print out human info, it should look like this:

```
================ 
Name   : Steven
Sex    : male 
Year   : 1970 
Father : NA 
Mother : NA 
Sig.O  : Eva
Child 1: Laura
Child 2: Alice 
================
```

above code is just representation without names I used in my main codes, just so you get what it is meant to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Review `strcpy(p->name, name);`.  When this is called, `p->name` is `NULL`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why is it NULL, shouldn't it take the name of abbas when I first summon person_constructor ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I turned it into     p->name = name;
 and it looks like it works but there are still so much flaws

Comment: `p = calloc(1,sizeof(*p));` set `p->name` to 0.  The happens before `strcpy()`.  `p->name` needs some allocated memory if you want distinctive names..  Try `p->name = strdup(name);`

Comment: Something wrong with 'children'. I could not find anywhere they are set, but the code still print them. The are declared as struct p**, but are used as string. Consider removing all cast like 'const char *)` to let the compiler tell you about type mismatches

Comment: @dash-o I removed all my const char* like stuff and now it prints name birth and sex pretty decently but wont print out significant other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically allocate C struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979879/dynamically-allocate-c-struct)

Answer (score 0):

Does your code compile on your machine, I tried and it does not on my machine. 
You need to fix the code first in order to compile it, like change this

```
Person *p = calloc(1,sizeof(*p));
```

to

```
Person *p = (Person *)calloc(1, sizeof(Person));
```

and also change `strcmp(p->father, "")` to `strcmp(p->father->name, "")`

p->father is not a string and instead a struct. You cannot compare a struct with a string.

Similarly do for the mother and children.

Comment: I can suggest more changes so that your code compiles well. Try yourself and let me know if further help needed.

Comment: I removed all strcpy and replace them with ones like     p->year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
It still doesn't work doe

Comment: The `calloc` statements are the same, but the 2nd one with the superfluous cast is way harder to maintain and read, (though C++ requires it.) `p->father` is not a valid pointer, then `p->father->name` is going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an issue in the person_constructor function. Try doing this:

```cpp
Person* person_constructor(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex)
{
    Person *p = (Person *)calloc(1, sizeof(Person));
    strcpy(p->name, name);
    p->year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
    strcpy(p->sex, sex);
    return p;
}
```

For the display_person function the parents are not strings, but pointers, so they are null or structs:

```cpp
void display_person(Person* p) {
    printf("================\n");
    printf("Name   : %s \n",p->name);
    printf("Sex    : %s \n",p->sex);
    printf("Year   : %d \n",p->year_of_birth);

    printf("Father : %s \n", p->father == null ? "N/A" : p->father->name);
    printf("Mother : %s \n", p->mother== null ? "N/A" : p->mother->name);

    printf("Sig.O  : %s \n", p->significant_other== null ? "N/A" : p->significant_other->name);
    printf("Child 1: %s \n", p->children[0]== null ? "N/A" : p->children[0]->name);

    //Others here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, one has defined:

[image: Person]

Then one uses `calloc` to get an instance of this:

[image: calloc Person]

Which is fine, but notice that the pointers are not valid. `strcpy` will on an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour. One could `p->name = name`, that would result in the compiler pointing `name` to the `name` parameter:

[image: p->name = name]

Since one is using [static constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) names, the name will never disappear and not be changed. This is good as long as one is controlling where the `name` comes from. Suppose `name` was input to a temporary `char *` before being passed to `person_constructor`; one would only have a defined `name` as long as the underlying temporary variable were present. A common way to avoid this is copying.

```
Person *p;
char *pname;
size_t name_len = strlen(name);
p = calloc(1, sizeof *p + name_len + 1);
if(!p) return 0;
pname = (char *)(p + 1);
strcpy(name, pname);
p->name = pname;
```

This copies `name` the parameter into the newly-formed `p` after the space where `p` is, (since one allocated that space.) The other option is to allocate a fixed maximum number of characters `name[200]` and copy the name directly in, (be careful that `strcpy` does not cause overflow.)

`strcmp(p->father,"")`, is passing `struct p` when it expects `const char *` (see [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html).) The `strcmp` function knows nothing about `struct p`, but will happily return extraneous values or crash. I would suggest setting the `father` explicitly to `0` (NULL) in the constructor, (this is not guaranteed to be all-bytes-zero,) then one can `printf("Father : %s \n", p->father ? p->father->name : "N/A");`.

The same thing with children, except `birth` causes the array to grow. If it's a dynamic array, one will need to `realloc` something. The alternative is to allocate a fixed maximum number of children.